# canvas taking more than 100% of the viewport

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, size

I recently started to study Canvas but since I stumbled upon a problem I couldn't seem to solve :

I simply tried to create a canvas that take the whole window, but as simple as it seems, i couldn't manage to get it right, it always take approximately 105% of both width and height of the window.

here's the code :

HTML :

```
<head>

    <title> Canvas Tests</title>
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>

    <canvas></canvas>
</body>
<script src="js/sketch.js"></script>
```

CSS

```
body,html{
    background : red;
    margin : 0;
}


canvas{
    background: blue;
    margin : 0;
}
```

js

```
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
console.log(canvas.width,canvas.height);
// output : 1536 759
```

I tried to replace the canvas tag by a div and set its width and height to 1536/759 and in that case it sizes properly.

The problem occurs in both chrome and firefox, and seems to only occur when I try to size a canvas. Any help is appreciated

Comment: the window.inner does not always give an accord value, do a google and you will find a way to find the min

Comment: Why don't you use 100vw and 100vh in css?

Comment: The same problem occurs wether I set the size manually via CSS or JS, no matter if I use percentage, vw, vh, or raw pixels.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `display:block` to your `canvas` :

```
canvas{
    background: blue;
    margin : 0;
    display:block;
}
```

or use `position : absolute;` with `left:0` and `right:0` to make it stretch along the window width

```
canvas{
   position: absolute;
   left: 0;
   right: 0;
   background: blue;
}
```

( i don't know why it's not working properly in the snippet below but here's a fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/7n760tpo/17/ )

```js
var canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
```

```css
body,html{
    background : red;
    margin : 0;
}

canvas{
    background: blue;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: Oh yeah, it works fine once displayed in block. Thank you very much. 
I do not understand however why it needs to be displayed this way, does the canvas actually conflicts with the body ?